# General Orientation Needed: What architectures/methodologies should I use to encapsulate a website to run on someone else's website (plug-in)?

Tags: plugins, hosting, subdomain, subdirectory

I have a product in mind that requires the development of a website that should run within another organization's current website. So, this would be a website that offers functionality that many other organizations would want to host on their own domain and use their user's current login credentials. A plugin so to speak.

How do I develop a module that exists and interacts with their website on their domain? I'd like to avoid an API that requires them to integrate (other than the credentials issue which I don't know how to get around yet). I would prefer this to be a plug-and-play solution where they buy the software from me, host it, and it seamlessly integrate into their site.

I don't have any specifics to offer. I need a general orientation.

Comment: Sorry, but your question is not very clear. If you want the company to integrate your program into their website then they will have to do all the work of 'integration' - it's almost never plug and play, unless their site is running on some sort of popular CMS platform such as WordPress or Joomla, in which case you could create a plug-configure-and play module for their website. If you want your site to run on theirs, then they would have to allow you to do so in the first place and then they will have to provide you with some sort of API to do so - it will not be plug and play either.

Comment: That's what my worry was. Okay, thanks.

Comment: So, the answer is: without a popular platform that allows you to integrate with it and everyone who is integrated with it to use your plugin, there is no other way but custom integration with custom communications. Can you answer and I'll accept?

Comment: Sure, I'll just copy your words, if you don't mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOTE: ANDED from the comments above:

..without a popular platform, such as WordPress or Joomla, etc., that allows you to integrate with it and everyone who is integrated with it to use your plugin, there is no other way but custom integration with custom communications.